# Is there a way to change the type of a scratch file in IntelliJ while in Distraction Free Mode?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm loving the fact that I can create scratch files on the fly in IntelliJ, but I'm noticing a caveat - I can't change the type of the scratch file  while I'm in Distraction Free mode.

I'm [well aware](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scratches.html#d676570e219) that I can use the status bar to switch it around, but if I'm in distraction free mode, I can't see it specifically (even when I double-tap ALT to view the status bar).

Is there a way for me to be able to switch out the language of a scratch file without having to disable distraction free mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** this only applies to IntelliJ 15 and newer, or JetBrains IDEs that are based on IntelliJ 15 or newer.

---

Two options for you:

**OPTION 1**

1. Open the `Find Action` dialog via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> / <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>
2. Search for *"Change File Language"*
3. Select *"Change File Language"* in the pop-up

**OPTION 2**

Map a keyboard (or mouse) shortcut to the *"Change File Language"* action in *Settings > Keymap > Other > Change File Language* and use it to invoke the action.

Comment: I'm not seeing those options available to me.

Comment: @Makoto I'm seeing those options, but only in IntelliJ 15 EAP. Perhaps it is a new feature that is not available in current stable release.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt:  I've been keen on giving the EAP a try, but I have to run the most current version of IntelliJ to ensure that it doesn't break my polyglot workflow.  I'll look into it.

Comment: This only works in the latest and greatest IntelliJ.  I'm accepting your answer and I'll revise it to incorporate that information.